# selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.AddonFormatError: ("[Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox-extension

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options    
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox/firefox')
ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
ffprofile.add_extension('/home/user/Desktop/exten/stylish.xpi')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=ffprofile)  # firefox_options=options)
link = driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDrTbLXHKu8')
```

Получаю :

> selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.AddonFormatError: ("[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpttv3ykej.stylish.xpi/install.rdf'", )

В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Добрый день, какую версию Firefox вы используете?

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что вы используете одну из версий Firefox Quantum (с 57-й версии включительно). На новом движке метаданные расширения хранятся не в файле install.rdf, а в файле manifest.json. В том собственно и проблема, Selenium ещё не умеет работать с новыми расширениями (научиться только в версии [3.14](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/f9f0f6b93dc3f38d082222fc70f0dab1467ea190)), и поэтому ищет внутри архива расширения файл install.rdf.

Вот [тут](https://intoli.com/blog/firefox-extensions-with-selenium/)

автор поста написал класс который несколько изменяет процедуру поиска метаданных в подключаемом расширении, благодаря чему selenium тянет инфу уже из manifest.json.

То есть, вам нужно:

```
# Добавить импорт
import json
import os
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import AddonFormatError 

# Добавить класс изменяющий процедуру поиска метаданных
class FirefoxProfileWithWebExtensionSupport(webdriver.FirefoxProfile):
    def _addon_details(self, addon_path):
        try:
            return super()._addon_details(addon_path)
        except AddonFormatError:
            try:
                with open(os.path.join(addon_path, 'manifest.json'), 'r') as f:
                    manifest = json.load(f)
                    return {
                        'id': manifest['applications']['gecko']['id'],
                        'version': manifest['version'],
                        'name': manifest['name'],
                        'unpack': False,
                    }
            except (IOError, KeyError) as e:
                raise AddonFormatError(str(e), sys.exc_info()[2])

# Объявить профиль Firefox не FirefoxProfile(), а созданным классом
profile = FirefoxProfileWithWebExtensionSupport()
```

Всё остальное продолжить делать как и раньше)))

Удачи)